# Service Bus 1.1 creating Queue with WindowsAzure.ServiceBus dll

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

I am preparing to develop application that connects to Azure Service Bus. For development I want use Service Bus 1.1.

I have installed localy Service Bus 1.1 and it works fine when I am connecting with package **Service Bus.v1_1 ver. 1.0.5**.

But as I want eventually work with Azure I prefer to use package WindowsAzure Service Bus which as I know sholud work with Service Bus 1.1.

But when I want to execute:

```
namespaceManager.QueueExists(queueName)
```

with **WindowsAzure.ServiceBus ver 3.1.2** package I receive:

`'System.ArgumentException' ....
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. The api-version in the query string is not supported. Either remove it from the Uri or use one of '2012-03,2012-08,2013-04,2013-07'.`

Adding `?api_version=2013-07` to Uri does not helps.

*However sending message to queue that exists on local SB1.1 works well (Using WindowsAzure.ServiceBys 3.1.2).* 
So it just applies to connections with NamespaceManager.

Could anyone has any ideas why it does not work ?

---

The code I use for tests:

```
var cs ="Endpoint=sb://mylocalmachine/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace/;StsEndpoint=https://mylocalmachine:9355/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace/;RuntimePort=9354;ManagementPort=9355";
var queueName = "AAA";
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(cs);
var messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(cs);
var ver = namespaceManager.GetVersionInfo();

if (namespaceManager.QueueExists(queueName))
{
    namespaceManager.DeleteQueue(queueName);
}

namespaceManager.CreateQueue(queueName);

QueueClient client = messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient(queueName);
client.Send(new BrokeredMessage("Hello! " + DateTime.Now));


client = messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient(queueName, ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
BrokeredMessage message = client.Receive();
if (message != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message.GetBody<string>());
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge the WindowsAzure.ServiceBus package is not compatible with on premises Windows Service Bus.  We are stuck with using the old package.

I believe the libraries are source compatible for most things, so when you DO migrate to using Azure service bus instead of on-prem, then it should be as simple as swapping out the package and changing the authentication mechanisms and connection strings and recompiling and testing.