# QueueClient Send throw "Could not connect to net.tcp://xxx.servicebus.windows.net:9354/" error

Tags: c#, .net, azure, tcp

I am using `Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll` (version 2.1) in order to work on Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1.

We also want this library to be able to talk to Azure Service bus.  It only works on the computer in one domain (no port restriction).  However on a computer in a more restricted domain (some ports are blocked), I got following error. If I switch `Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll` 3.0, then the same code works in the restricted domain.  Why does `Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll` 3.0 work and `Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll` 2.1 does not work in the same lab (domain)?

> Could not connect to net.tcp://xxx.servicebus.windows.net:9354/. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:20.9992011. 
>   TCP error code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established 
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 40.86.102.100:9354.
>    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>      at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.RunSynchronously()
>      at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageSender.OnSend(TrackingContext trackingContext, IEnumerable`1 messages, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageSender.Send(TrackingContext trackingContext, IEnumerable`1 messages, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageSender.Send(BrokeredMessage message)
>      at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QueueClient.Send(BrokeredMessage message)

When I used Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll 3.0 to talk to SB for Windows Server 1.1, I got the following error:
"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. The api-version in the query string is not supported. Either remove it from the Uri or use one of '2012-03,2012-08,2013-04,2013-07'."

Based on this link [Service Bus 1.1 creating Queue with WindowsAzure.ServiceBus dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34767609/service-bus-1-1-creating-queue-with-windowsazure-servicebus-dll), I have to use Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll 2.1.
I would like to use a Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll version that can talk to both Azure Service bus and SB for Windows Server 1.1.  It seems 2.1 is the only choice, but it give me 
trouble in that restricted domain.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll 3.0 work and Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll **3.1**

Based on your description, It seems you write wrong version of Microsoft.serverBus.dll 3.1. Can we understand as version 2.1?

From the Microsoft Azure Service Bus release note, we could find below information:

• General: Compiled against .Net 4.5 - .Net 4.0 projects will need to recompile against .Net 4.5 as well.
• General: Removal of old Begin/End style async API for all Messaging and EventHub classes. Please use Task base async API instead.

The version above 3.0 will compiled against .Net4.5. So if your application use .Net 4.5. It is better to choose the version of Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll higher than 3.0.

Comment: Right, I meant to say Why does Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll 3.0 work and Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll 2.1?  Sorry for the typo.
I added two paragraphs in the original question describing the issues in using Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll 3.0 or higher version.